# How to list down Only the years from specific date on database up to now, using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, list

I want to display a list of years in a drop down, which goes from now to 'established_on' date in database table. And those lists of years should be list of links of years which leads to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your model is called `Post`, then you can get the distinct years from the database by doing a query,

```
Post.distinct.select("date_trunc('year', created_at) AS creation_year")
```

This will give you all the distinct years that are present in the created_at column. Then if you want to filter the Posts by year, you can use,

```
Post.where("date_trunc('year', created_at) = '2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'")
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Controller:**

```
@club_years = @club.established_on.year..Date.today.year
```

**In view:**

```
<% @club_years.each do |n| %>
   <%= link_to n, '#', class: 'dropdown-item' %>
<% end %>
```